# Re-use variables/objects in callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I was wondering this, in the following example, what would be the best way to handle re-use my `helpers` object?

```
var test = {
  Projects: 'an object goes here',
  helpers: require('../helpers'),

  test: function(req, res) {
    if (this.helpers.is_post(req)) {
      // tried this
      var test = this.helpers;

      this.Projects.byCode(req.params.project_code, function(project) {
        if (!project) {
          this.helpers.flash(req, 'error', 'Unable to find project.');
          // tried this
          helpers.flash(req, 'error', 'Unable to find project.');
          res.redirect('/projects');
        }
      });
    }
  }
};
```

I know I can't re-use variables, objects, etc in callbacks since they're not execute during the same runtime, but still there must be some kind of better/clearer way of doing such a thing?

Even if I tried to reassign this.helpers to another variable, it gives me errors saying that it is undefined.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you think you cannot re-use variables inside callbacks? They are executing not only in the same runtime, but in the same thread! That's the beauty of JavaScript.

Instead, your problem is likely a misuse of this. For example, it will definitely not work without the assignment to `var test = this.helpers`. And even that won't work if you call the method like so:

```
var testIt = test.test;
testIt(req, res);
```

Try something like the following instead:

```
var helpers = require('../helpers');

var test = {
  Projects: 'an object goes here',

  test: function(req, res) {
    if (helpers.is_post(req)) {
      this.Projects.byCode(req.params.project_code, function(project) {
        if (!project) {
          helpers.flash(req, 'error', 'Unable to find project.');
          res.redirect('/projects');
        }
      });
    }
  }
};
```

It's really pretty nonsensical to put an entire module as a property of your object, anyway.